# Add my application to "Enter Text From" option in Compose Message activity in the SMS application

Tags: android, android-intent

I tried a lot but no luck..

I couldn't figure out how i can add my application to the "Enter Text From" option in the Messaging application comes with android.

There must be a way of doing that, so probebly the experts here can help here..

(Instructions:)

1. Enter to the Messaging application in android
2. Click on Compose New Message
3. Click Menu Button
4. Choose "Enter Text From" option

OR:

Just click on the button with Attachment icon which open an Attachment Dialog:

[image: Attachment Dialog]

Comment: FWIW, my copy of the Messaging application does not have an "Enter Text From" action bar overflow item. You might want to post screenshots of the menu and the chooser that you get when selecting that menu choice, since not everyone will be able to reproduce your steps.

Comment: you right. What about an Attachment button where you can attach (VIDEO \ AUDIO \ PHOTO \ MEMO and so on..) have you got this option in messaging app ?

Comment: Yes, I have that. You will not be able to add yourself to that particular immediate list ("Pictures", "Capture picture", etc.), you can arrange to be in the chooser for one (or more) of those options. For example, supporting `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` for a MIME type of `image/*` might add you to either the "Pictures" or "Capture Picture" choosers.